# Bottom half of UITabBar was cover by the phone itself

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, cut

I have this application which have 3 screen for now. The first screen has UItableView with NavigationController. The second screen is still UITableView which drill down from the first one. On the third page I tried to call tabbarcontroller  but when the view appeared, my tabbar was cut to half of the original size. Here is the snippet.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
    // Custom initialization

}

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];}
```

!

Anybody? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {

if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {

```
// Custom initialization
```

}

[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];

[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];

}